# Method of Characteristics for parametric problems

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

I am considering the equation

$u_t(t,x,\eta)+V(t,x,\eta)\cdot u_x(t,x,\eta)=0$

where $V:[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,1]^D\to \mathbb{R}^n$.
For the parameter independent case, one would solve this equation via the method of characteristics.

Is there also literature for the parameter-dependent case?
What does the relevant ODE system look like now? Like this?

$\gamma_t(s,\eta)=V(s,\gamma(s),\eta)$

$\gamma(t_0,\eta)=x_0$

And what are the characteristic curves? Maybe

$\{(s,\eta,\gamma(s,\eta) \ | \ s \in [0,T]\}$?

Comment: What do you mean by parameter independent and parameter dependent? What parameter? Where is the parameter you are talking about?

Comment: $\eta$ is the parameter. Parameter-independent means that V does not depend on $eta$ and therefore also the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The pde $u_t + V u_x = 0$ is a linear advection equation, where $V(t,x; \eta)$ may be dependent on time, space and a parameter $\eta$, e.g.
$$
V(t,x;\eta) = e^{-\eta t} - \eta x.
$$
The method of characteristics for the initial-value problem $u(0,x; \eta)=u_0(x)$ gives

- $\frac{\text d}{\text ds} t = 0$, letting $t(0)=0$ gives $t=s$;
- $\frac{\text d}{\text ds} x = V$, letting $x(0)=x_0$ gives $x$ in terms of $s$, $\eta$ and $x_0$.
- $\frac{\text d}{\text ds} u = 0$, letting $u(0)=u_0(x_0)$ gives $u=u_0(x_0)$.

The characteristic curves aren't straight lines in general, but $u$ will be constant along these curves. With the example above, we find $x(s) = (x_0 + s)  e^{-\eta s}$, so that $u(t,x; \eta)=u_0(x e^{\eta t} - t)$.